# make something a required field depending on value

Tags: infopath, custom-list, validation

How can I make a column required depending on another columns value.
Is it possible to do this without javascript?

Comment: Your question is unclear. You tagged it with infopath and validation, then in the question text you cited javascript. Please clarify the exact scenario and requirement that you have. As it stands, I see it as a candidate for a close vote

Comment: You can do that in InfoPath with rules

Answer (score 0):

Dave,  the only way i can think of is adding jQuery script on your new form that checks the values,  since this is a custom logic depending on the field value.

Comment: This surely isn't the only way. The poster needs to clarify his question